# How can I upgrade the existing XAP in the WP8 device programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have an application which is side-loaded in the device.Now, I would like to give the application capability to upgrade itself programmatically. Is it possible, if I get the latest XAP from a server through HttpWebRequest and install it in the device? Is there any API available to install the XAP programmatically?

Comment: Imagine if it were possible. Why would we even bother going through marketplace certification?

Comment: Yes I agree with you KooKiz, actually this is an enterprise app (Signed) installed through built-in company app. When I tried upgrading it through browser (on navigating to latest XAP path), it got upgraded (existing one got replaced with latest). That's the reason I thought to look for a programmatic way to simulate the same.

Comment: Oh, if it's an enterprise app then it's different. I don't remember the details, but I think the company hub has access to the necessary APIs to update apps

Comment: HI harshbodhi, wanted to check if you got an answer for this. I am looking for the same functionality. Is it possible to upgrade itself programatically.

Comment: Hi Rao, There is no programmatic way to self-upgrade the app though it can upgrade other apps. Workplace(Built-in MDM) has the ability to push the update.